# Why was this question deleted by Community?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I understand question deletion by moderators, but I cannot understand why this question was deleted by the Community user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208544/

Please could somebody explain this to me.

Comment: Interesting. It has upvoted answers, so it shouldn't get auto-deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user account from which the question was posted was deleted by SE, at the account owner's request.  Questions with a score below zero are automatically deleted by the system when an account deletion takes place.  That's what happened here.

Comment: I thought questions that are upvoted or have upvoted answers are spared. hmm...

Comment: The question was at -1 when it was deleted.  The answers seems to suggest a mundane syntax error.

Comment: Right, but I (wrongly) believed that having upvoted answers would be enough to block the auto-deletion. (since we don't want to "lose valuable answers")

Comment: Not for a destroy operation.

Comment: Ah. Good to know.

Comment: Yeah, destroy is not [mostly dead](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9tAKLTktY0).  Destroy is check the pockets for loose change.

Comment: Was this a reflection on the quality of the question, the user's profile or is it following some principle that SE will delete all content including related content when asked?

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: The OP posted two questions before requesting account deletion.  Both questions were very basic; both had a score of -1 at time of deletion.  See my answer update.