# My question was deleted by Community♦

Tags: feature-request, support, deleted-questions

[My question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198287/add-zero-score-posts-to-topbar)* (10k+ link) was deleted by Community♦. Why?

I searched a little and found reasons for deletion like [rejected migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170974/why-was-my-answer-deleted-by-community) or [account deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203050/why-was-this-question-deleted-by-community). But I can't see why my post was deleted.

I don't care about it being undeleted. I just want to know why. And in the process I would find it great if we display a reason when a question gets deleted out of the blue.

<sub>* 1 month old, 2 up- and 3 downvotes</sub>

Comment: @shog9: My question is only a month old.

Comment: 30-day rule - see linked question

Comment: @Shog9 wow I wasn't aware it's active here on Meta - it means tons of not-so-popular feature requests are being wiped, I don't think it's right.

Comment: Meh @ShaWizDowArd, we're usually not a quiet bunch. I don't think that answerless requests are all that common.

Comment: @Bart feature requests usually receive only comments, especially if not so popular, don't think they deserve insta-death like that.

Comment: 57 in the last month, @Sha

Comment: @Shog9 and what *you* think? Do all of them really deserve to be deleted? I've seen some cases of negative scored requests being eventually implemented. [Good example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112836/152859).

Comment: Eh; there are [some decent ones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196943/allow-users-of-a-certain-reputation-to-force-approve-a-suggested-edit) and a lot of dups, @Sha. Critically, none of them managed to attract any answers (though in some cases an awful lot of comments were generated). There's an argument to be made that a poorly-received proposal is better off removed so that someone else can write a better one - sometimes, the *way* in which something is suggested does more to bury an idea than the nature of the idea itself.

Comment: @Shog9: Now I feel offended ;-)

Comment: Heh... In your case, [that stuff's all gonna change soon anyway](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-multicollider-redesign) - best see how that pans out before suggesting tweaks.

Comment: @Shog9: Yeah I know that post. I was just kidding.